# Is there a layout to place 2 same sized images in two columns on the WordPress page?

Tags: images, css, front-end

I need to place two images on a landing page of a WordPress site as below. I don't find a suitable layout option under Flexible Content field group that fits my requirement. I believe I should be able to create a layout to handle my needs. Question is how to add such a layout?

[image]

Comment: The “Flexible Content” field is an Advanced Custom Fields plugin feature, not a WordPress feature. How exactly are you editing your pages?

Comment: I edit them in the edit screen. I think something like duplicating an existing layout for Text and Full Image and manipulating this will help.

Comment: @Jacob, Hi, I've a WordPress page built with DIVI builder that has multiple <title> tags as verified with its view source page. I don't find the <title> tag in the Divi builder's sections so I can remove the duplicates. Can you share your thoughts on locating the full HTML of this page https://andersonadvisors.com/how-to-structure-a-business-workshop-training/ in the WordPress admin or Divi builder?